# Java - issue with generics

Tags: java, generics

How do I properly design this, so it would work:

In class `Property<E>`:

```
public void addPropertyChangedListener(OnPropertyChangedListener<E> listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

In class `ViewModelBase`:

```
public void addPropertyChangedListener(String propertyName, OnPropertyChangedListener<?>   listener) {
    Property<?> property = properties.get(propertyName);
    property.addPropertyChangedListener(listener); // I get error here
}
```

Error I get:

```
The method addPropertyChangedListener(Property.OnPropertyChangedListener<capture#5-of ?>)
in the type Property<capture#5-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments
(Property.OnPropertyChangedListener<capture#6-of ?>)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `properties.get(PropertyName)` is a `Property`, correct?

Comment: Generalizing Jason Cs comment: Some more code showing the involved classes may be helpful - particularly, showing where `E` is defined.  You can't add a `...Listener<?>` where a `...Listener<E>` is expected, but it's hard to say more based on the current code.

Comment: Just make the method generic.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Which one?

Comment: The `ViewModelBase.addPropertyChangedListener` and use the type variable everywhere you are using `?`.

Comment: Is there any way to deal with unchecked excepetion then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void <T> addPropertyChangedListener(String propertyName, OnPropertyChangedListener<T>   listener) {
    Property<T> property = (Property<T>)properties.get(propertyName);
    property.addPropertyChangedListener(listener);
}
```

There is no way to avoid an unchecked cast warning if `Properties` is a heterogeneous collection.  How does it even make sense (in a type system as weak as that of Java) to statically typecheck something whose type can only be known at runtime?